# git-tf clone exception java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

I am trying to use git-tf to clone a TFVC project on TFS. When I run git-tf clone I am prompted to enter my TFS username and after entering my username, I get a java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError.
My goal is to migrate this project to Git and push it to Gitlab while maintaining the changeset history of course.

**Command:**
git-tf clone https://tfs-url/tfs/defaultcollection/  $/TFSProjectName  ~/Desktop/MyTFSProject --deep

**Full Exception:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 'boolean com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.nativeEnableEcho()'
    at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.nativeEnableEcho(Native Method)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.internal.console.NativeConsole.enableEcho(NativeConsole.java:56)
    at com.microsoft.tfs.jni.ConsoleUtils.enableEcho(ConsoleUtils.java:47)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.prompt(Command.java:510)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.promptForPassword(Command.java:482)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.promptForCredentials(Command.java:470)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getDefaultCredentials(Command.java:309)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getCredentials(Command.java:335)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.framework.Command.getConnection(Command.java:370)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.commands.CloneCommand.run(CloneCommand.java:203)
    at com.microsoft.gittf.client.clc.Main.main(Main.java:328)
```

**Environment:**

- **OS**: MacOS Catalina 10.15.5
- **Java**: openjdk 11.0.7 2020-04-14
- **Git-tf**: git-tf version 2.0.3.20131219

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, the cause of this issue is the java version.

Check this doc about [Git-TF](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=gittf). You could download the **Java 7** and set it as **the PATH environment variable**.

Test with Java 8 and it could also work.

On the other hand, Git-TF has reached its end-of-life.

> My goal is to migrate this project to Git and push it to Gitlab while
> maintaining the changeset history of course.

I recommend you to use [Git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) to achieve it.

Here are the script:

```
git tfs clone <TFS URL> $/project

cd repo path

git checkout -b TempBranch 

git remote add origin <Git URL>

git push --set-upstream origin TempBranch
```

In this case, the TFVC Repo could be changed as Git repo. Then you could use git push to push the Repo to Gitlab.

It will keep the history too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! but as far as I know, Git-tfs doesn't work on MacOS (https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/758) and that's why I went for git-tf.

Comment: I have tried to install java 7 and added it to the $PATH and also set $JAVA_HOME with /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/ but still, the same error occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your information. After installing the Java, have you tried to restart the machine? If this issue still exists, could you please try other git-tf commands (git-tf configure)? You could check if other commands have the same issue.